# How to keep a console c# application running and reading input from standard input stream (not continously)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application

I have a console c# application (native messaging app) which is connected to a WinForms via named pipes. console app is a native messaging app connected with chrome. WinForm send the command to console app to start reading standard input stream to get messages to chrome and send it to WinForm.
I dont know how to keep the console app alive so that it can wait for the events attached to get command from winform and read the standard input stream.?

This is my main function.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
         StartChannel();            
}
```

This is the Event handler for getting message from named Pipe

```
public void StartChannel()
{
    _pipeServer = new PipeServer();
    _pipeServer.PipeMessage += new DelegateMessage(PipesMessageHandler);
    _pipeServer.Listen(AppConstant.IPC_ConsoleReaderPipe);
}

private void PipesMessageHandler(string message)
{
  if(message ="Start")
       StartListener();
}
```

**This is my problem center. Here after executing StartListener,console application closes. How can i I keep it running in a separate thread. So that it should not block the the NamedPipe communication **

```
private static void StartListener()
{
        wtoken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        readInputStream = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            wtoken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            while (true)
            {
                if (wtoken.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    wtoken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                else
                {
                   OpenStandardStreamIn();
                }
            }
        }, wtoken.Token);
    }
}


public static void OpenStandardStreamIn()
{
    Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
    int length = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    stdin.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
    length = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    string input = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        input += (char)stdin.ReadByte();
    }
    Console.Write(input);
}
```

Comment: @Alex: Console.ReadLine will not work in case of reading the Console.OpenStandardInput(); in   OpenStandardStreamIn(); . May be i should paste code of that also. See my edit.

Comment: Yep just saw your comment. I have no idea :)

Comment: @Alex : No Issues. :)

Comment: So, when this console application should exit? Any Wait operation on event can keep it alive. If you want to stop such program from another process, use named event. You can also set this event if something wrong happens in the pipe.

Comment: @AlexFarber : Thanks, I will try it Alex and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You should try using an `AutoResetEvent` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx.
This way, your main thread waits on the listener thread until the event is set and only terminates after that.
If you are using .NET 4.5, you should use the `async` and `await` keywords plus `Task.Run()` -> see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx